# Why is the specified width value being ignored for this image?

Tags: css, next.js

[image]

I am currently developing with Next.js and using the  component provided by Next.js.
We are using the same component, but why is the image below ignoring the specified width value that I have set?
The structure of the component is as follows.

```js
interface IcontextProps {
  src: string;
  alt: string;
  width: number;
  height: number;
  text: string;
}

export default function IconText({
  src,
  alt,
  width,
  height,
  text,
}: IcontextProps) {
  return (
    <div className={styles['icon-text-wrapper']}>
      <Image
        className={styles['icon']}
        src={src}
        alt={alt}
        width={width}
        height={height}
      />
      <span>{text}</span>
    </div>
  );
}

--------- css
.icon-text-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  span {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}
```

I am importing and using it as follows in main.tsx.

```js
          <div className={styles['event-info-top-wrapper']}>
            <div className={styles['event-date-wrapper']}>
              <IconText
                src={'/assets/glimpse-list/calendar-icon.svg'}
                alt={'달력 아이콘'}
                width={24}
                height={24}
                text={'2023/12/13'}
              />
              <IconText
                src={'/assets/glimpse-list/clock-icon.svg'}
                alt={'시계 아이콘'}
                width={24}
                height={24}
                text={'8:00 PM (EST)'}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <IconText
                src={'/assets/glimpse-list/location-icon.svg'}
                alt={'위치 아이콘'}
                width={24}
                height={24}
                text={'Seoul, Korea'}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
------ css
      .event-info-top-wrapper {
        padding-bottom: 16px;
        .event-date-wrapper {
          display: flex;
          gap: 8px;
        }
      }
```

Thank you for providing the solution and explanation. Could you please explain the reason behind the solution

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specified value is not ignored. Your icon is 24px width and height. The issue is that your div is 100%. Which makes component expand to end. Solution would be is to add event-date-wrapper to iconText below.

here's the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/why-is-the-specified-width-value-being-ignored-for-this-image-r6fwqw)

```
<div className={styles['event-info-top-wrapper']}>
            <div className={styles['event-date-wrapper']}>
              <IconText
                src={'/assets/glimpse-list/calendar-icon.svg'}
                alt={'달력 아이콘'}
                width={24}
                height={24}
                text={'2023/12/13'}
              />
              <IconText
                src={'/assets/glimpse-list/clock-icon.svg'}
                alt={'시계 아이콘'}
                width={24}
                height={24}
                text={'8:00 PM (EST)'}
              />
            </div>
            <div className={styles['event-date-wrapper']}>
              <IconText
                src={'/assets/glimpse-list/location-icon.svg'}
                alt={'위치 아이콘'}
                width={24}
                height={24}
                text={'Seoul, Korea'}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
```